# Access State from a StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

What is the correct way to acces a StatefulWidget's State from within the StatefulWidget?

I have tried having a instance variable in the StatefulWidget class and setting that with "widget._state = this;" in the "initState()" method in my State class, but sometimes it is null?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, no.

`StatefulWidget` is purely immutable. It cannot contain anything mutable.

Comment: Ofcourse yes :) Can I get a hold on its State, maybe via context or something? I just need to trigger a method on the state from outside

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is a callback function

Comment: I need to call a method on the state from outside, from where I use the widget.